# Why am I getting undefined for the input field jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The

```
if($('input[name=answer-opt]:checked').val() == templatePos)
```

never returns true, even though the numbers "conceptually" match.

I've tried several methods of doing this, including converting *templatePos* to a string or the input form value to a number, but nothing seems to work.

I've got the following code:

```
$(document).on("click", "#guess-btn", function() {
    if(templateCorrect === null) {
        // Remove the guessing form
        $("#guess-container").remove();
        // Get the position of the correct answer
        var templatePos = positions.indexOf(0)+1; 
        if($('input[name=answer-opt]:checked').val() == templatePos) {
            templateCorrect = true;
            count++;
        } else {
            templateCorrect = false;
        }
        positions = showAnswer(currentData, "Twitter");
)};
```

Why won't this return true and how do I fix it?

UPDATE:
Here is the function that inserts the html containing the relevant input fields

```
function showAnswer(data, stage) {
    var positions;
    displayNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
    switch(displayNum) {
        case 0:
            firstOption = data["template"];
            secondOption = data["twitter"];
            thirdOption = data["reddit"];
            positions = [0,1,2];
            break;
        case 1:
            firstOption = data["template"];
            secondOption = data["reddit"];
            thirdOption = data["twitter"];
            positions = [0,2,1];
            break;
        case 2:
            firstOption = data["reddit"];
            secondOption = data["template"];
            thirdOption = data["twitter"];
            positions = [2,0,1];
            break;
        case 3:
            firstOption = data["reddit"];
            secondOption = data["twitter"];
            thirdOption = data["template"];
            positions = [2,1,0];
            break;
        case 4:
            firstOption = data["twitter"];
            secondOption = data["reddit"];
            thirdOption = data["template"];
            positions = [1,2,0];
            break;
        default:
            firstOption = data["twitter"];
            secondOption = data["template"];
            thirdOption = data["reddit"];
            positions = [1,0,2];
    }
    $("#search-container").remove(); // Removes the search box
    $("#description-container").remove(); // Removes the description
    $("#title-container").after(
        '<div id="guess-container">' +
        '   <div class="row">' +
        '       <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-3">' +
        '           <h2>Which answer came from ' + stage + '?</h2>' +
        '       </div>' +
        '   </div>' +
        '   <form name="guess-form" id="guess-form">' +
        '       <div class="row">' +
        '           <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-3">' +
        '               <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="answer-opt" value="1" />' +
        '               <label id="answer-btn-1" for="radio1">'+ firstOption +'</label>' + 
        '           </div>' +
        '       </div>' +
        '       <div class="row">' +
        '           <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-3">' +
        '               <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="answer-opt" value="2" />' +
        '               <label id="answer-btn-2" for="radio2">'+ secondOption +'</label>' +
        '           </div>' +
        '       </div>' +
        '       <div class="row">' +
        '           <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-3">' +
        '               <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="answer-opt" value="3" />' +
        '               <label id="answer-btn-3" for="radio3">'+ thirdOption +'</label>' +
        '           </div>' +
        '       </div>' +
        '   </form>' +
        '   <div class="row">' +
        '       <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-3">' +
        '           <button id="guess-btn" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Guess</button>' +
        '       </div>' +
        '   </div>' +
        '</div>'
    );
    return positions;
}
```

UPDATE 2:
After further inspection and modification, I'm now getting the value of the input type as undefined. I really can't work out why. Here is my full js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var positions;
var currentData;
var twitterCorrect = null;
var redditCorrect = null;
var templateCorrect = null;
var count = 0;
$("#ask-btn").click(function () {
    if(!$("#question").val()) {
        // The input field is empty so do not submit

    } else if(!($("#question").val().match(/[a-z]/i))) {
        alert("You're question must contain at least one letter!");
    } else {
        var q = $("#question").val();
        var url = "/answer.php?q="+q;
        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            currentData = data;
            /* positions is an array containing the ordering of the responses.
            0 = template,
            1 = twitter,
            2 = reddit.
            */
            positions = showAnswer(currentData, "our AI");
        });
    }
});
$(document).on("change", "input[type=radio]", function() {
    $("#guess-btn").prop("disabled", false);
});
$(document).on("click", "#guess-btn", function() {
    if(templateCorrect === null) {
        $("#guess-container").remove(); // Remove the guessing form
        var templatePos = positions.indexOf(0)+1;
        var temp = $('input[name=answer-opt]:checked').val();
        console.log(temp);
        console.log(typeof(temp));
        var num = parseInt(temp,10);
        console.log(num);
        console.log(typeof(num));
        if(num === templatePos) {
            console.log("template");
            templateCorrect = true;
            count++;
        } else {
            templateCorrect = false;
        }
        positions = showAnswer(currentData, "Twitter");
    } else if(twitterCorrect === null) {
        $("#guess-container").remove(); // Remove the guessing form
        var twitterBtn = "#answer-btn-" + (positions.indexOf(1)+1).toString();
        if($(twitterBtn).is(':checked')) {
            console.log("Twitter");
            twitterCorrect = true;
            count++;
        } else {
            twitterCorrect = false;
        }
        positions = showAnswer(currentData, "Reddit");
    } else if(redditCorrect === null) {
        $("#guess-container").remove(); // Remove the guessing form
        var redditBtn = "#answer-btn-" + (positions.indexOf(2)+1).toString();
        if($(redditBtn).is(':checked')) {
            console.log("reddit");
            redditCorrect = true;
            count++;
        } else {
            redditCorrect = false;
        }
        console.log(count);
        displayResults(count, templateCorrect, twitterCorrect, redditCorrect);
    } else {
        console.log("Error with the results process");
    }
});
});


function displayResults(count, templateCorrect, twitterCorrect, redditCorrect) {
    $("#title-container").after(
        '<div id="results" class="row">' +
        '   <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-3">' +
        '       <h2>You Got ' + count.toString() + '/3 Right</h2>' +
        '       <a href="/ask">Ask another question</a>' +
        '   </div>' +
        '</div>'
    );
}
```

Comment: I assume your actual code has the `});` that is missing from the end here. That said, can can you show us your html?

Comment: I believe the value of radio buttons returns a string try using parseInt

Comment: @Binvention I've tried doing that and parseInt() returns NaN

Comment: What value does the radio button value return. Like console log the result and see what it has.

Comment: It changes based on the input, but it always returns the same "conceptual" value as templatePos. The type is string.

Comment: Did you make sure to use base 10 with the parseInt

Comment: So you know that the value is returning a number inside a string like this "2" but when you try and use parseInt("2",10) it doesn't work?

Comment: @Binvention when I do parseInt($('input[name=answer-opt]:checked').val(), 10) it doesn't work

Comment: Does parseFloat work? I don't know of anything else

Comment: Create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=JVVAMAAEQm It works on this link, which would suggest something else is causing my problem.

Comment: What do you see in the console once `console.log($('input[name=answer-opt]:checked').val())` is executed?

Comment: @AlexanderElgin undefined

Comment: Oh I found it you need to wait to remove your guess form from the Dom until after you checked your value